# Plotting latitudes / longitudes in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-maps

I want to plot few latitudes / longitudes in the Google maps using python. I tried to use the iPython JuPyter notebook. I have tried the following packages,

```
import gmaps
import gmaps.datasets
import gmaps.geojson_geometries

gmaps.configure(api_key="API key")

locations = gmaps.datasets.load_dataset("taxi_rides")

fig = gmaps.figure()
fig.add_layer(gmaps.heatmap_layer(locations))
fig
```

I am getting the following as output

[image]

if I try the same thing in iPython shell, I get the following

[image]

I am not able to view the images which has been plotted.

I tried other packages such as,

```
import gmplot

gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(37.428, -122.145, 16)

gmap.draw("mymap.html")
```

But didnt get any output from the package.

Can anybody help me in plotting the points in google maps ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need widget extensions enabled for your jupyter installation.
Enable it by running in your terminal:

```
$ jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension
```

Also, tell jupyter to load the gmaps extension with:

```
$ jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix gmaps
```

### Reference:

- [nbextensions](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Distributing%20Jupyter%20Extensions%20as%20Python%20Packages.html)
- http://jupyter-gmaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html